# Can i re-pass the object as received to another component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to pass an object from Home -> Header -> Tabs. Is this possible with props?

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html); also if you think you have to pass an object across multiple layers/components, you can use [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: @SreetamDas Object passing is not allowed in useContext?

Comment: yes, you can. You should check out the examples in the docs itself, they're pretty helpful :)